# How to reduce length of and edge between two nodes without affecting a custom line marker?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I'm drawing some nodes with `to and from` edges with some of the edges red, and with a cross through it. I have a custom decoration for the cross, and draw a red arrow head at the end of the line. In trying to `shorten` the line, to avoid it going out of the arrow head bounds, I find that the custom marker is also shortened.

What I have so far is as shown in the code and image below. Is there a way can shorten the line without affecting the cross, or even a better way to do this in general?

Thanks for your help!

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.shapes,decorations.markings}
\tikzset{
  shift left/.style ={commutative diagrams/shift left={#1}},
  shift right/.style={commutative diagrams/shift right={#1}},
  crossed/.style={draw=red,shorten >= 1.8pt,
    decoration={markings, mark= at position .15 with
      {
          \draw[red] (-2pt,-2pt) -- (2pt,2pt);
          \draw[red] (2pt,-2pt) -- (-2pt,2pt);
      };,
      mark= at position 1 with {\arrow[red]{>}};
    },
    postaction={decorate},
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    mynode/.style={rectangle,draw=black,thick,inner sep=0pt, minimum size=4mm},>=latex',
]

  \node[mynode,font=\tiny] (m0) {0};
  \node[mynode,right=of m0,font=\tiny] (m1) {1};

  \path[shift left=.75ex,thick]
  (m0) edge[->] node[very near start, yshift=-0.5ex, xshift=0.5ex,  font=\tiny] {2} (m1)
  (m1) edge[crossed] node[very near start, yshift=0.5ex, xshift=-0.5ex,  font=\tiny] {4} (m0);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This gives me:

[image]

Without the `shorten` command, I get:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For arrow head, you don't need `mark`. Add `->` directly to the edge. Then for your decoration, you have to add `-` like,

```
\draw[red,-] (-2pt,-2pt) -- (2pt,2pt);
\draw[red,-] (2pt,-2pt) -- (-2pt,2pt);
```

so that they don't have arrow heads too.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.shapes,decorations.markings}
\tikzset{
  shift left/.style ={commutative diagrams/shift left={#1}},
  shift right/.style={commutative diagrams/shift right={#1}},
  crossed/.style={draw=red,%shorten >= 1.8pt,
    decoration={markings, mark= at position .15 with
      {
          \draw[red,-] (-2pt,-2pt) -- (2pt,2pt);
          \draw[red,-] (2pt,-2pt) -- (-2pt,2pt);
      };,
      %mark= at position 1 with {\arrow[red,anchor=west]{>}};    %% not needed here
    },
    postaction={decorate},
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    mynode/.style={rectangle,draw=black,thick,inner sep=0pt, minimum size=4mm},>=latex',
]

  \node[mynode,font=\tiny] (m0) {0};
  \node[mynode,right=of m0,font=\tiny] (m1) {1};

  \path[shift left=.75ex,thick]
  (m0) edge[->] node[very near start, yshift=-0.5ex, xshift=0.5ex,  font=\tiny] {2} (m1)
  (m1) edge[crossed,->] node[very near start, yshift=0.5ex, xshift=-0.5ex,  font=\tiny] {4} (m0);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you insist on using the arrow head as a mark, then add `shorten >= 0pt` to the decorative cross lines too like

```
 \draw[red,shorten >= 0pt] (-2pt,-2pt) -- (2pt,2pt);
 \draw[red,shorten >= 0pt] (2pt,-2pt) -- (-2pt,2pt);
```

so as to prevent them from getting shortened.