# Shortening and decorating a path

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-decorations

Placing an arrow as decoration on a path which has been shortened leads to a misplacement of the arrow. This is potentially emphasized if the `looseness` key has been used. In [this other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25830/decoration-at-end-of-line-after-shorten-command) (and also [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238634/how-to-reduce-length-of-and-edge-between-two-nodes-without-affecting-a-custom-li)), the problem has been noticed, but I do not understand if there is a general way to make the `shorten` key interact with a decoration getting the naively expected result.

In the MWE below, you can see that not shortening the (orange) path leads the
(black) arrow to be centered on it, while shortening the (blue) path makes the (red) arrow misplaced.

```
\documentclass[border =3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\tikzset{
    mid arrow/.style={postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,mark=at position .35 with {\arrow[#1]{stealth}}}}},
    connect/.style={shorten >= #1 mm, shorten <= #1 mm, out=0, in=180, looseness=2},
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (A) at (0,0); \coordinate (B) at (2,1);
        \path[draw=blue] (A) edge[mid arrow=red, connect=1] (B);
        \path[draw=orange] (B) edge[mid arrow=black, connect=0] (A);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, if the shorten routine provided by Ti*k*Z does not do what you want, you may build your own. Here is a proposal inspired by [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/270007/121799). The idea is to measure the length of the path and then switch the drawing off and on. (**UPDATE**: Add `dash phase=0.0001pt`, a trick discovered by the OP, that avoids a very tiny point at the beginning of the path, which I failed to spot when I posted the earlier versions of this answer.)

```
\documentclass[border =3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\newlength\mylen
\newlength\vislen
\newlength\hidlen
\tikzset{
    mid arrow/.style={postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,mark=at position .35 with {\arrow[#1]{stealth}}}}},
    connect/.style={
    decoration={
    markings,
    mark=at position 0.5 with {
      \node[draw=none,inner sep=0pt,fill=none,text width=0pt,minimum size=0pt]
      {\global\setlength\mylen{\pgfdecoratedpathlength}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\hiddenlength}{#1 mm}
      \global\setlength\hidlen{\hiddenlength pt}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\visiblelength}{\pgfdecoratedpathlength-2*\hidlen}
      \global\setlength\vislen{\visiblelength pt}
      };
    },
  },
  preaction={decorate},
  dash pattern=on 0pt off \hidlen on \vislen off \hidlen, 
  dash phase=0.0001pt, 
    out=0, in=180, looseness=2},
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (A) at (0,0); \coordinate (B) at (2,1);
        \path[draw=blue] (A) edge[mid arrow=red, connect=1] (B);
        \path[draw=orange] (B) edge[mid arrow=black, connect=0] (A);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Let me stress that this is not a real alternative of Ti*k*Z' shorten (yet). For instance, if you were to add arrow heads by simply saying `\draw[->]`, this won't work, i.e. the arrow heads would just sit at the position of the target, but a bit of the curve would be missing. (However, you could of course easily add arrow heads wherever you want them.)

**ADDENDUM**: Just for fun, added a more flexible style `myconnect` which allows one to skip different amounts at the beginning and at the end of the path, and also double-checked that for curves with controls everything works fine.

```
\documentclass[border =3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\newlength\mylen
\newlength\vislen
\newlength\hidlen
\newlength\firstlen
\newlength\secondlen
\tikzset{
    mid arrow/.style={postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,mark=at position .35 with {\arrow[#1]{stealth}}}}},
    connect/.style={
    decoration={
    markings,
    mark=at position 0.5 with {
      \node[draw=none,inner sep=0pt,fill=none,text width=0pt,minimum size=0pt]
      {\global\setlength\mylen{\pgfdecoratedpathlength}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\hiddenlength}{#1 mm}
      \global\setlength\hidlen{\hiddenlength pt}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\visiblelength}{\pgfdecoratedpathlength-2*\hidlen}
      \global\setlength\vislen{\visiblelength pt}
      };
    },
  },
  preaction={decorate},
  dash pattern=on 0pt off \hidlen on \vislen off \hidlen,
  dash phase=0.0001pt,  
    out=0, in=180, looseness=2},
}

\tikzset{myshorten/.style n args={3}{#1,
    decoration={
    markings,
    mark=at position 0.5 with {
      \node[draw=none,inner sep=0pt,fill=none,text width=0pt,minimum size=0pt] 
      {\global\setlength\mylen{\pgfdecoratedpathlength}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\hiddenlength}{#2}
      \global\setlength\firstlen{\hiddenlength pt}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\hiddenlength}{#3}
      \global\setlength\secondlen{\hiddenlength pt}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\visiblelength}{\pgfdecoratedpathlength-\the\firstlen-\the\secondlen}
      \global\setlength\vislen{\visiblelength pt}
      };
    },
  },
  preaction={decorate},
  dash pattern=on 0\mylen off \firstlen on \vislen off \secondlen,
  dash phase=0.0001pt
  }
}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (B) at (2,1); \coordinate (C) at (5,5);
        \path[draw=red] (B) edge[mid arrow=blue,myshorten={out=0, in=180, looseness=2}{5mm}{7mm}]
        (C);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
     \coordinate (B) at (2,1); \coordinate (C) at (3,5);
     \draw[gray,connect=0] (B) .. controls ++(0:1.75) and ++(180:1.75) .. (C);      
     \draw[mid arrow=red,connect=10] (B) .. controls ++(0:1.75) and ++(180:1.75) .. (C);        

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The gray curve in the right picture is just to verify that the curve does not get deformed.

Comment: Very nice, I like your idea a lot. And I have to admit that I would have rather naively expected this as default behavior of shortened decorated paths. Anyway, the dash pattern, despite the initial `on 0pt`, draws an almost invisible dot at the starting point. A `dash phase=0.01pt` would remove it shifting imperceptibly the drawn path, but it sounds to me as a patch. Is there a more elegant way to fix this minor aspect?

Comment: @AxelKrypton A very good catch! I didn't spot that! Perhaps your suggestion is the easiest way out? According to what I see, even `dash phase=0.0001pt` does the job. (Sometimes one has to help Ti*k*Z a little bit.) If you agree, I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Yes, you are right. `dash phase=0.0001pt` also does the job and I hardly believe it could be a problem for anyone. I cannot think of anything better for the moment, so an update would be welcome. :)

Comment: @AxelKrypton Will do. But which version do you want, the first or the more flexible one (or both)?

Comment: I think indeed the second, more flexible one is enough and it somehow contains the first. And it can be easily used or adapted to symmetrically shorten the path. But I leave the edit up to you!

Comment: @AxelKrypton ... too late ;-) I already updated both.... (It is actually even simpler to skip a certain percentage of the path... perhaps one can add this at a given point... a somewhat bigger challenge would be to move arrow heads to the beginning and/or end of the visible path ) This was a fun problem, and I agree with you that something along these lines should be the Ti*k*Z default.

Answer (score 2):

Just a little better ... **And the problem is the same with `controls` or `arc`, see below.**

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\tikzset{
    mid arrow/.style args={#1 at #2}{%  #2 not 0 or 1 exactly
        decoration={%
            markings,
            mark = at position #2 with {%
                % what ever you want, as if you were in a scope
                % the coordinate system tangential
                \draw[#1,-stealth] (0,0)--(1pt,0pt);
            }
        },
        postaction={decorate}
    },
    connect/.style={out=0, in=180, looseness=2, shorten >= #1, shorten <= #1},
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
        \coordinate (B) at (2,1);
        \path[draw=blue] (A) edge[mid arrow=red at .35, connect=1mm] (B);
        \path[draw=orange] (B) edge[mid arrow=black at .35, connect=1mm] (A);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

#### To discuss the first remark in the comment (and to add more arrows in the race).

The problem is more complicated than just switching the decoration step (placing the arrow on the path) and the shorten step, because the black arrow follows the orange line but with gray tangential coordinate.

Switching the two steps is not enough: the `shorten` action introduces a twist in the new path (the two paths are no more on the same drawn line) and, furthermore, a shift in `pos`ition. Therefore, the tangential coordinates are calculated on the original path and are no more tangential to the new twisted drawn line.

`pos` offset = 0.025 :

[image]

No `pos` offset :

[image]

The twist: starting and ending points are shifted and leave the initial line and the in and out angles stays the same. `shorten` does not make the line shorter, it rather creates a new one! Here, with a shorten of `10`, the red arrow should be on the dark blue line while it stays on the pale one, which is the original without shortening.

[image]

#### The problem is the same with `controls` or `arc`

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\tikzset{
    mid arrow/.style={postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,mark=at position .35 with {\arrow[#1]{stealth}}}}},
    connect/.style={shorten >= #1 mm, shorten <= #1 mm,  looseness=2},
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (A) at (0,0); \coordinate (B) at (2,1);
        \draw[mid arrow=red,connect=10] (A) .. controls ++(0:1.75) and ++(180:1.75) .. (B) ;
        \draw[mid arrow=black,orange] (B) .. controls ++(0:1.75) and ++(180:1.75) .. (A) ;
        \draw[blue] (2,0) arc (0:45:2) ;
        \draw[blue,mid arrow=red,connect=10] (2,0) arc (0:45:2) ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I see your idea. However, the tangential coordinate system scope seems to be tangential to the not shortened path, as it can be seen drawing a longer tangent segment as `mark` instead of an arrow `\draw[#1] (0,0)--(5mm,0pt);`. As if the decoration were done at first and the shortening of the path (changing its shape) after. Am I completely mistaken and/or is there a way to flip the order of these operations?

Comment: By the way, your GIF is very cool. I could spend hours looking at it. I think I will start making "arrow races" on `tikz` paths. :)

Comment: A race with no suspense

Comment: @AxelKrypton Last workaround and edit.

Comment: I edited your answer (without changing it) to make it more pedagogical for the new reader. Thanks for the added information. With `shorten` of 10 the problem is manifest. I still do not perfectly understand why to create the new, shortened path and *then* decorate it (if possible) would still not fix the problem. In any case, it seems there is not a real solution. Does it mean that it is better to avoid to combine `shorten` and `decoration` together as much as possible (e.g. calculating first the starting and ending point of the shortened path and then using a normal decorated path)?

Comment: How did you create these nice animations? That is, could you please teach me the commands or software you are using to make these? And which LaTeX packages did you use? animate?

Comment: @marmot I made a pdf with one tikzimage per frame in beamer with a foreach loop. Then import the pdf in Gimp with one page per calc, cut at the right size, reverse the order of calc, then export as tiff.

Comment: Merci! Yes, for beamer I am also able to do that. ([This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23728/121799) may be even simpler and if that does not work, [this chain](http://phyletica.org/imagemagick/) should.) I was wondering if you found out to do that with inline animations using the animate package.

Comment: Does tex produce giff directly ? Even with animate package you produce a pdf ?