# Why do I get an arrowhead in the middle of a circle?

Tags: tikz-pgf

The follow code produces an arrowhead at the centre of the circles. Can anyone please explain why and how to remove it?

```
\tikzset{pics/carc/.style args={#1:#2:#3}{
code={\draw[pic actions] (#1:#3) arc(#1:#2:#3);
}}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[<-,>=stealth', thick, black] (0,0) pic{carc=100:440:1.6};
\draw[<-,>=stealth', thick, black] (0,0) pic{carc=100:440:1.1};
\draw[<-,>=stealth', thick, black] (0,0) pic{carc=100:440:0.6};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Please, don't post fragments but a minimal example from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `\draw` by `\path` then the arrow to `(0,0)`, which is the end of your the path, will not be drawn:

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{pics/carc/.style args={#1:#2:#3}{
  code={\draw[pic actions] (#1:#3) arc(#1:#2:#3);
}}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[<-,>=stealth', thick, black] 
  (0,0) foreach \r in {1.6,1.1,.6}{pic {carc=100:440:\r}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I really like your simple loop, but I think that the path solution is perhaps not optimal. [Sometimes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/419482/121799) the paths get distorted by options like `shorten`. In the above situation, of course there is none of these issues.

Answer (score 3):

The arrow is there because you asked Ti*k*Z to put it. I guess you want to pass the options to the `\draw` inside the pic, not to the outside one.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{pics/carc/.style args={#1:#2:#3}{
code={\draw[pic actions] (#1:#3) arc(#1:#2:#3);
}}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw (0,0) pic[<-,>=stealth', thick, black]{carc=100:440:1.6};
 \draw (0,0) pic[<-,>=stealth', thick, black]{carc=100:440:1.1};
 \draw (0,0) pic[<-,>=stealth', thick, black]{carc=100:440:0.6};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]