# Decorate a circle ending decoration "exaclty"

Tags: tikz-decorations

I would like to decorate a circle in a way such that the starting and the ending points of the decoration coincides in *a nice way*. Of course, they always coincide, but I would like to have the element of the decoration repeated an integer number of times. Is there an easy way to achieve it? Of course, adjusting the `amplitude` and/or the `segment length` of the decoration can help, but it needs a manual fine tuning, which I would like to avoid.

I looked in the [`pgf` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), in particular chapter 24, but I did not find my answer. As side remark, section 24.3 contains part of my code with the same "problem" and nothing in section 24.4 (Adjusting decorations) or 48.2 (Path Morphing Decorations) was for me useful.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[decorate, decoration=zigzag] (0,0) circle (1cm);
        \draw[decorate, decoration=bumps]   (3,0) circle (1cm);
        \draw[red, thick] (1,0) circle (3mm) (4,0) circle (3mm); % <- Just to stress the problem
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One ad hoc proposal is to set the segment length to pi mm (for circles of radius 1cm).

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[decorate, decoration={zigzag,segment length=3.14mm}] (0,0) circle (1cm);
        \draw[decorate, decoration={bumps,segment length=3.14mm}]   (3,0) circle (1cm);
        \draw[red, thick] (1,0) circle (3mm) (4,0) circle (3mm); % <- Just to stress the problem
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**UPDATE**: A more complete solution for zigzag.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,decorations.pathmorphing}
\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
    pattern repetition/.store in=\PatternRepetition,
    pattern repetition=20
}

\pgfdeclaremetadecoration{closing zigzag}{initial}{%
 \state{initial}[width=0pt, next state=zigzag] {
    \pgfmathdivide{\pgfmetadecoratedpathlength}{\PatternRepetition}
    \let\pgfmetadecorationsegmentlength\pgfmathresult
    \pgfset{/pgf/decoration/segment length=\pgfmathresult pt}
  }
\state{zigzag}[width=\pgfmetadecorationsegmentlength, next state=zigzag] {
\decoration{zigzag}
}
\state{final}
  {
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}
  }
}

% does not quite work yet 
\pgfdeclaremetadecoration{closing bumps}{initial}{%
 \state{initial}[width=0pt, next state=bumps] {
    \pgfmathdivide{\pgfmetadecoratedpathlength}{\PatternRepetition}
    \pgfset{/pgf/decoration/segment length=\pgfmathresult pt}
    \pgfmathdivide{\pgfmetadecoratedpathlength}{\PatternRepetition}
    \let\pgfmetadecorationsegmentlength\pgfmathresult
  }
\state{bumps}[width=\pgfmetadecorationsegmentlength, next state=bumps] {
\decoration{bumps}
}
\state{final}
  {
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}
  }
}

\newlength{\totallength}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[decorate, decoration={closing zigzag}] (0,0) circle (1cm);
    \tikzset{pattern repetition=55}
    \draw[decorate, decoration={closing zigzag}]   (3,0) circle (1cm and 2cm);
    \draw[red, thick] (1,0) circle (3mm) (4,0) circle (3mm); % <- Just to stress the problem
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, yes, ad hoc solution, but easily generalizable. Fair enough! I would have expected `tikz` to provide something to somehow make this available through a kind of interface or key, though.

Comment: @AxelKrypton Well, you'll always have to know the circumference of the cyclic shape you'd like to decorate, right? In the case of a circle, that's of course simple, but what if some one draws some complicated parametric plot? Or is your idea to get the `decoratedpathlength` and set the `segment length` to be an integer fraction thereof? That would be a nice thing, which I'll be happy to do a bit later. (BTW, +1)

Comment: You are absolute correct and I was also thinking that it should be possible to play with the `decoratedpathlength` in order to guarantee an integer repetition of the decoration item. This is what I had in mind when I wrote that I would have expected `tikz` to somehow provide a feature like that (but probably there are good reasons which go beyond my knowledge if such a feature is missing). If you feel like later to provide an example to how to generalize the code to a more complicate case, I will be happy to read and use it. And, of course +1, :)

Comment: @AxelKrypton I'll do it later, if I succeed. Just adopting the trick from [your nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/425170/121799) doesn't work in my first attempt, and now I'll have to do other things. Of course it is perfectly fine if you do it yourself, after all I'd only use a trick you invented. ;-)