# Draw a line not touching edges

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex

I'm drawing a line between 2 nodes and I'd like to avoid to touch the nodes, I have been able to do it with the first node but not with the second.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}


\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]



\tikz[baseline] \node[fill opacity=0.1,circle,label=left:2016,fill=black,inner sep=3pt] at (0,0) (n1) {};
\tikz[baseline] \node[draw=none,fill=none,align=left] {
  \vbox{
    bar
  }
};
\tikz[baseline] \node[draw=none,align=left] {
  \hspace*{20mm}\parbox{10cm}{
    foo
  }
};

\tikz[baseline] \node[fill opacity=0.1,circle,label=left:2016,fill=black,inner sep=3pt] at (0,0) (n2) {};
\tikz[baseline] \node[draw=none,fill=none,align=left] {
  \vbox{
    bar
  }
};
\tikz[baseline] \node[draw=none,align=left] {
  \hspace*{20mm}\parbox{10cm}{
    foo
  }
};
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
  \draw (n1)++(0, -0.25) -- (n2)++(0, 0.25);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

https://www.overleaf.com/project/5c00283f4365993602702d4f

Comment: Try `\draw ([yshift=-0.1cm]n1.south) -- ([yshift=0.1cm]n2.north);`. (And replace `\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]` by `\tikzset{every picture/.append style={remember picture}}`) Not sure if I would draw this picture in the way you do, why don't you just draw one picture?

Comment: It works nicely, thanks again @marmot. I also replaced the section you mentioned. I'm not using one picture because I'm mixing text and a few nodes, if I used \begin{tikzpicture} It would not allow me to use some commands. Probably because I do not know Latex

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your setting, you'd only need to use `\draw ([yshift=-0.1cm]n1.south) -- ([yshift=0.1cm]n2.north);`. However, one can draw your picture in a single picture without `remember picture`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[fill opacity=0.1,circle,label=left:2016,fill=black,inner
sep=3pt,label={[xshift=5mm]right:bar},label={[xshift=2mm,yshift=-5mm]right:foo},] (N1){};
\node[below=1cm of N1,fill opacity=0.1,circle,label=left:2016,fill=black,inner
sep=3pt,label={[xshift=5mm]right:bar},label={[xshift=2mm,yshift=-5mm]right:foo}] (N2) {};
\draw ([yshift=-0.1cm]N1.south) -- ([yshift=0.1cm]N2.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**: Using [Zarko's way](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/462445/121799) to define a universal style, one could use `outer sep` to produce the gaps. I would rather *not* use shorten as this can have unwanted side-effects if you consider using curved paths.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pfft/.style={circle,fill opacity=0.1,fill=black,inner
sep=3pt,outer sep=1mm}]
\node[pfft,label=left:2016,,label={[xshift=5mm]right:bar},label={[xshift=2mm,yshift=-5mm]right:foo},] (N1){};
\node[below=1cm of N1,pfft,label=left:2016,label={[xshift=5mm]right:bar},label={[xshift=2mm,yshift=-5mm]right:foo}] (N2) {};
\draw (N1) -- (N2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: When did `shorten` get deprecated? It is still used in the examples in the `3.0.1a` manual.

Comment: @PeterGrill I do not think it got officially deprecated. However, it can cause issues on curved paths, see e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/419482/121799). So I do not see that it is better than the `yshift` solution, rather it can backfire.

Answer (score 4):

And a third option, without `yshift` and without `outer sep` but `shorten` option in line between nodes:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3.141592mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 12mm,
   dot/.style = {circle, fill=black, fill opacity=0.1,
                 inner sep=3pt, %No outer sep like in Zarko's answer
                 node contents={}}
                        ]
\node (n1) [dot, label=left:2016, label={[xshift=3mm]right:bar}, label=below right:foo];
\node (n2) [dot, label=left:2017, label={[xshift=3mm]right:bar}, label=below right:foo,
            below=of n1];
\draw[shorten >=2pt, shorten <=2pt] (n1) -- (n2); %No `yshift` like in Marmot's answer
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

as complement to nice @marmot answer:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3.141592mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 12mm,
   dot/.style = {circle, fill=black, fill opacity=0.1,
                 inner sep=3pt, outer sep=2pt,
                 node contents={}}
                        ]
\node (n1) [dot, label=left:2016, label={[xshift=3mm]right:bar}, label=below right:foo];
\node (n2) [dot, label=left:2017, label={[xshift=3mm]right:bar}, label=below right:foo,
            below=of n1];
\draw (n1) -- (n2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]